# Why does my NumPy function not work out the cosine of two vectors?

Tags: linear-algebra, python

I have this function to work out the cosine between two vectors, except it isn't working for some reason.

```
def length(x):
    return math.sqrt(x.dot(x))


def unitVectorNormalize(u):
    if length(u) == 0:
        return "Your vector is null."
    return u / length(u)


def cosine(vector1, vector2):
    return vector1.dot(vector2) / (unitVectorNormalize(vector1) * unitVectorNormalize(vector2))
```

Is there something I am doing wrong?

> I am aware that there is a NumPy method to figure out the cosine similarity, but I am told (for my course) to write my own fucntion.

Comment: The formula is $\cos \theta = \mathbf a \cdot \mathbf b / (\lvert \mathbf a \rvert \lvert \mathbf b \rvert)$, which is not what you've implemented - the denominator should be `length(vector1) * length(vector2)`

Comment: [StackOverflow has a NumPy tag.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/numpy) Your question is much more appropriate there.

Comment: I am surprised that numpy can divide by vectors ...

Comment: @MaximilianJanisch that's fairly common in statistical computing, it's just "vectorisation" - which is componentwise applying some operation.

Comment: @IzaakvanDongen Oh yes of course, interestingly I didn't think about it here even though I use vectorized functions all the time :)

Comment: Wow, I feel silly. Maths isn't something I do much of, but I have to do it for my CS course. I thought the formula showed that the it was to be divided by the unit vectors of _a_ and _b_.

Comment: Not to worry :) We all have these moments. Just be clear on the notation - $\lvert \mathbf a \rvert$ is always a *length*, unit vectors are sometimes written $\hat{\mathbf a}$. (unrelated tip - I'd use `raise ValueError("Cannot normalise null vector")` or something along those lines.

Comment: [A shorter solution](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.14.0/reference/generated/scipy.spatial.distance.cosine.html) is `1-scipy.spatial.distance.cosine(vector1, vector2)`.